# Transcoding, noise reduction, enhancing the audio file

Tags: android, audio, cloud-service, vlc

I have checked zencoder & AWS elastic transcoder, but they don't seem to have the options for noise reduction or improving the voice clarity. Are there any cloud services which does this? 
Are there any command-line tools with these options. I have checked ffmpeg it has noise reduction, but it doesn't seem have enhancing option.

We are collected user's recording using his android mobile and intend to transmit to other people, but with better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SoX (Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), "the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation"):

- free
- open source
- Windows / Linux / Mac
- CLI
- some options might help improving the voice clarity but unsure, it depends on the kind of audio transformations you plan to apply.

[SoX manual](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html).